# ngTable tableParams count vlue being ignored

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have set up an ngTable and the following tableParams:

`var selectedItems = []; 
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 5           // count per page
        }, {
            total: selectedItems.length, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                $defer.resolve(selectedItems.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });`

The content of "selectedItems" is updated via a $scope.$watch that monitors the users selection from another "screen" in the single page application. However, after the user makes their selection, the "count" property in the tableParams is being ignored and it is displaying all 15 rows with no pagination options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues with ngTable pagination and for those with the same problem the fix is to reference the ngTable `$data` scope within the `ng-repeat` directive (regardless of where/how you store the table data).

i.e. `<tr ng-repeat="item in $data">`

It appears that `$defer.resolve()` will assign table data (i.e. `selectedItems`) to the `$data` scope to observe model mutations - which is tricky since referencing `selectedItems` in `ng-repeat` still displays the data (just without pagination!).